# What is wrong with my MySQL query (UNION)?

Tags: mysql, join, union

I hope you can get me here. I'm working on a PMS system and I want to run a simple SELECT statement to get a list of secret codes for my customers based on which of their parcels have arrived and the transaction type. The 'transferConfirmation' table already has the customer ID and the secret code and displays one row for each instance but for some reason, when i use the following query:

```
SELECT `tc`.`transferID` AS `transferID`,
       `c`.`firstName` AS `firstName`,
       `c`.`lastName` AS `lastName`,
       `tc`.`secretCode` AS `secretCode`,
       'Purchase Order' AS `transactionType`
FROM (((((`db`.`transferconfirmation` `tc`
          JOIN `db`.`customer` `c` on((`tc`.`customerID` = `c`.`customerID`)))
         JOIN `db`.`transfer` `t` on((`t`.`transferID` = `tc`.`transferID`)))
        JOIN `db`.`transferentry` `te` on((`t`.`transferID` = `te`.`transferID`)))
       JOIN `db`.`purchaseorder` `po` on((`te`.`referenceID` = `po`.`purchaseOrderID`)))
      JOIN `db`.`purchaseorderentry` `poe` on(((`po`.`purchaseOrderID` = `poe`.`purchaseOrderID`)
                                               AND (`te`.`referenceEntryID` = `poe`.`purchaseOrderEntryID`))))
WHERE (`poe`.`collectionStatus` = 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT `tc`.`transferID` AS `transferID`,
       `c`.`firstName` AS `firstName`,
       `c`.`lastName` AS `lastName`,
       `tc`.`secretCode` AS `secretCode`,
       'Shipping Order' AS `transactionType`
FROM (((((`db`.`transferconfirmation` `tc`
          JOIN `db`.`customer` `c` on((`tc`.`customerID` = `c`.`customerID`)))
         JOIN `db`.`transfer` `t` on((`t`.`transferID` = `tc`.`transferID`)))
        JOIN `db`.`transferentry` `te` on((`t`.`transferID` = `te`.`transferID`)))
       JOIN `db`.`shippingorder` `so` on((`te`.`referenceID` = `so`.`shippingOrderID`)))
      JOIN `db`.`shippingorderentry` `soe` on(((`so`.`shippingOrderID` = `soe`.`shippingOrderID`)
                                               AND (`te`.`referenceEntryID` = `soe`.`shippingOrderEntryID`))))
WHERE (`soe`.`collectionstatus` = 0)
```

I keep getting results with duplicate data only difference is with the transaction. I guess my question is, if the secret code has been selected once, how to I prevent any other row from displaying the same code.

Comment: Please Format your query. It is unreadable.

Comment: It is indeed unreadable, but he only wants to get unique results, so --- add DISTINCT(<field>) on every <field> you do not want to get duplicate values.

Comment: Sorry about my query. Will the second part of the UNION also ignore the duplicate code from the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `UNION` operator.  The `UNION` operator will remove duplicate records from each query (`UNION ALL` would retain them).

```
SELECT transferID, firstName, lastName, secretCode,
    'Purchase Order' AS transactionType
FROM ...
UNION
SELECT transferID, firstName, lastName, secretCode,
    'Purchase Order' AS transactionType
FROM ...
```

Comment: that works for each part of the UNION, but not for them combined

Comment: @BrodaTherapy Use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.